# ggplot2 with mtcars: How does it know car class?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a beginner with R going over the ggplot2 tutorial and something has caught my eye as being bizarre when using the mtcars dataset.

For example, consider the following:

```
>library(ggplot2)
>g<-ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
>g
```

I can't figure out why this works. This clearly makes a plot with the counts of each car class (2seater, compact, midsize, minivan, pickup, subcompact, suv).

My question is: How does R/ggplot know what classes these cars are in? There is no variable in the mtcars data.frame that describes this:

```
>mtcars$class
NULL
```

Is this something just built into the ggplot package?

Comment: try with `mpg$class`

Comment: You're using the `mpg` data frame in your `ggplot` code, not the `mtcars` data frame. The `mpg` data frame is built into the ggplot2 package (run `data(package="ggplot2")`), while the `mtcars` data frame is included in base R.

Comment: @eipi10 your comment is the answer, and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `mpg` data frame in your ggplot code, not the `mtcars` data frame. Your code is:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
```

`mpg` is the data argument. But if you change to

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(class)) + geom_bar()
```

you'll get an error, because the `mtcars` data frame does not have a column called `class`.

The `mpg` data frame is built into the ggplot2 package. Run `data(package="ggplot2")` to see which data sets come with `ggplot2`. The `mtcars` data frame is included in base R. Run `data()` to see data sets available from all loaded packages.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed something so simple. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: how awesome, the exact same thing happened to me :-D